# Link for switch language

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

How do I make a link to switch the language, without using any modules? When users click on a language I want to switch language and redirect them to the same page not to front page.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are already using the [Internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) (i18n) module. i18n provides the Language Switcher block, which contains links to switch among all enabled languages. When the user chooses one of the links in it, he is redirected to the corresponding page rendered in the newly-selected language.

Note that the block is only shown if at least two languages are enabled and language negotiation is set to something other than None.

Comment: Yes I'm using i18n, but as I said I don't want to use language switcher block because site's theme is already created and I don't want to spend time for theming language switcher block

Comment: Your question does not mention the language switcher block. I believe that theming the switcher block will be much less work than implementing your own switcher.